# php multiple alternate column loop

Tags: php, recordset, calculated-columns, alternate

im very new to php and html and im trying to create an ouput like this coming from a database table recordset. where "table record n" is the column from the db table record set

basically the table will be a 1x2x1x2x4 columns with 5 rows

```
<table border=1>
    <tr> 
        <td>table record 1 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <td> table record 2 </td> <td>table record 3 </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr> 
        <td> table record 4 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> table record 5 </td> <td>table record 6 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> table record 7 </td> 
        <td>table record 8 </td>
        <td> table record 9 </td> 
        <td>table record 10</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

i only got as far as this one

```
          $next_Column = 1;


          echo "<tr>";

           while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) 
           { 
    echo "<td>". $row['name']. "</td>"; 
    $next_Column ++;

    if( $next_Column > 1 )
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        $next_Column = 1;
    }
       } 
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above loop will always echo a `<tr>`, because when you get to the `if`, `$next_column` will always be > 1.  You need to use nested loops to loop through the columns. Something like the code on [this page](http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2009/01/13/print-all-mysql-database-tables-fields-using-php/) should help. Although, if you KNOW you need it in that exact format, why not just make your php like this?

```
<table border=1>
<?php
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
    {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row[0] . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row[1] . '</td><td>' . $row[2] . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row[3] . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row[4] . '</td><td>' . $row[5] . '</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>' . $row[6] . '</td><td>' . $row[7] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row[8] . '</td><td>' . $row[9] . '</td></tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Note that all those numbers can be replaced with column names in quotes (like `'name'`). Also, the above code will emit 5 table rows for EVERY ROW in the database.  Is that what you are looking to do?

EDIT: If you are trying to loop through each row and add it to a table based on THAT ROWS number of columns, then I would suggest something like this:

```
<table border=1>
<?php
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
    {
        echo '<tr>';

        //Loop through cols
        foreach($row as $value)
        {
            if($value)
            {
                echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
            }
        }

        echo '</tr>'
    }
?>
</table>
```

This will put the value in the table row ONLY IF it is in the database, so if you have a row with 1 filled column, you get 1 table column, but a row with 4 columns filled will have 4 table columns.

Comment: well, replace your while loop with the one I wrote above and give it a shot, let me know how it goes.

Comment: hi @SuperTron the sample scenario is like this `<tr> 
   <td> userid 1 </td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr> 
   <td> userid 2</td> <td>userid 3 </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr> 
   <td> userid 4 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td> userid5 </td> <td>userid6 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td> userid7 </td> 
   <td>userid8 </td>
   <td> userid9 </td> 
   <td>userid10</td>
  </tr>` where userid is individual columns from the table itself

Comment: yes, then the above code should echo that for each row in a the database, assuming the information is there.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @SuperTron :) each row is one distinct record i tried the code that youve supplied it displays the format in one sweep what im trying to accomplished is similar to the layout of this one http://www.cashcashpinoy.com/ wherein each image is one distinct record from the database

Comment: Oh, so you wanna loop through the rows and display a different number of columns based on how many there are?

Comment: yes, exactly i got stucked on that. it should follow the order 1x2x1x2x4

Comment: Yeah, please try my edited solution then. I would also appreciate an upvote if I helped in any way ;)

Comment: i got a css design that has a 5 rows with 1x2x1x2x4 columns meaning row one has one rectangular columns and row 2 has 2 columns and so on. each html column(td's) contains an individual record therefore column 1 will contain record id 1 from the table. http://www.qualitycodes.com/tutorial.php?articleid=33&title=Displaying-Records-in-Multiple-Columns-Using-PHP

Comment: Yeah I don't understand what you mean. What is wrong with the second solution I posted above?

Comment: it should follow the pattern 1x2x1x2x4

Comment: go to [the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5782/discussion-between-oliver-sakkam-and-supertron) like you posted.

Comment: sorry to bother you chat is not working on my side you got gmail? btw i tried this one `$m = array("one" ,"two" , "two", "one", "two","two","four","four","four","four");
$y=array(1,2,1,2,4);

 echo '<table border=1>';
  foreach (array_chunk($m, 1) as $row)
  { 
   echo'   <tr>';
     foreach ($row as $value) 
     { 
         echo '<td>'.htmlentities($value).'</td> ';
      } 
  echo'    </tr>';
   
 }
 echo '</table>';` how do i make the 2nd parameter of the array_chunk dynamic so that it will follow the pattern 1x2x1x2x4

Comment: Yes, I have gmail, give me your email and I'll add you.

Comment: its toliveistocherish@gmail.com :)